# Monitor a postman collection

Tags: api, postman, postman-collection-runner

how do I use a data file to monitor my postman collection? I read in the Postman [Documentation](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/monitors/intro_monitors/) that it is not possible to use a data file as we use for collection run but we can access Google docs, google sheets etc. I don't understand how do we import these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can send a binary file as part of the request body while using the Postman App. However, the same functionality is not available in a monitor run. You cannot specify a binary file to be sent as the request body.

Depending upon the file that you're sending, you can use the `raw` request body type to send the same file. Simply copy the contents of the file that you would normally send in the App, select body type as `raw` and paste that in the request body.

Note: This might not work with all file types.